# What does "it's you lot" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've just finished watching "Pride" and one thing stays unclear to me. There was a scene where a guy comes up to a group of women and asks  with a dose of anger in his voice **"It's you lot, is it? The gays?"** What exactly "lot" does here? Thanks for help.

Comment: "You lot"  means "you people" in British English.

Comment: Lot as noun check [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lot#nav3) sense 1 and 1.1 . (ODO)

Comment: It's how a future pillar-of-salt in the Old Testament summoned her husband.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"You lot" is a mainly British colloquialism for "You people", but perhaps with a slightly greater sense of defining the people addressed as subordinate to the speaker. It's not necessarily derogatory, although the example above seems to suggest discrimination, but it usually indicates the speaker is asserting some sort of authority.

A policeman might say to a group of teenagers crowding around a vehicle accident: "You lot - get out of here!"

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that Americans never say *Hey, you lot...* Or something like *this lot are far better than the last lot*, when talking about any group from the government to the office cleaners.

Comment: @WS2 -  but it's true- we don't say it.  *Hey you guys.*  *This group's a lot better than the last one*  Even *crop*-  This crop's a lot better than the last one.

Comment: In the south, "y'all" serves a similar purpose.